# Using Apache and mod_ext_filter, need to dynamically replace values of static file based off of query string

Tags: ruby, apache

I've got a situation where I need to alter the contents of a cached file based off of one of the query string arguments passed in.  I'd love to use sed to do a simple regular expression replacement of a value based off of said argument but I can't figure that one out.  I could use a ruby script to do the replacement for me but can't seem to access the query string for the request within the script.  The documents for mod_ext_filter say:

> In addition to the standard CGI environment variables, `DOCUMENT_URI`, `DOCUMENT_PATH_INFO`, and `QUERY_STRING_UNESCAPED` will also be set for the program.

Um yeah, can't seem to access those.

Has anybody any experience with this or does anybody have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!  Looks like I simply need to access the `ENV` variable within ruby.  Pretty dumb of me.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP scripting language server function we can able to get the query string values.
`echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`
And pass the URL arguments as a variable to the file and make it dynamic.

Refer : [PHP.net](http://in.php.net/reserved.variables.server)